# Pip Proxy Error

Tags: pip

Im trying to install some pip packages behind a proxy. Ive set the env to,

```
http_proxy=http://172.16.2.3:3128
https_proxy=http://172.16.2.3:3128
```

I then tried pip but get the error,

```
[root@server ~]# pip install --proxy=http://172.16.2.3:3128 virtualenv -v
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 122, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 424, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))
Collecting virtualenv
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/virtualenv/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /simple/virtualenv/
```

However curl appears to work (?)

```
[root@server ~]#    curl -I https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
HTTP/1.1 200 Connected

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-PYPI-LAST-SERIAL: 1916396
Cache-Control: max-age=600, public
X-Clacks-Overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why have you marked it down ?

Comment: try specifing the proxy manually: pip install --proxy=http://proxy_url:proxy_port ... + when curling specify the -v flag to see what's going on: curl -v -I https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/ Paste back the outputs you get.

Comment: Your pip command is correct, I've tried it on my machine with another proxy server and it works. Which pip version are you using? (`pip --version`)

Answer (score 15):

You can specify the proxy as a parameter to pip install:

```
pip install <package> --proxy http://your.proxy.net:8080/
```

If you also face ssl certificate errors (also common in corporate environments), you can enable pypi as a trusted host as well:

```
pip install <package> --proxy http://your.proxy.net:8080/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

Comment: This did it for me!

Answer (score -8):

This issue can be solved running in terminal

```
./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && make install
```